# Xamarin CrossMediaManager cannot queue from PlayfromResources

Tags: xamarin.forms, plugin.media.crossmedia, plugin.mediamanager.forms

I am trying to Queue all MP3 files in Embedded resources using
CrossMediaManager PlayFromAssembly(string, assembly);
Play from assembly only supports string name of single file theres no way of adding multiple files from embedded resources.

Appreciate any help from yours.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a list to add resources by url like this:

```
 public IList<string> Mp3UrlList => new[]{
        "https: a,
        "https: b,
        "https: c,
        };
    
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(Mp3UrlList);
```

Second, this method can play the resourses in the folder, here is the code:

```
await CrossMediaManager.Android.PlayFromResource(Resource.Raw.somefile.ToString());
```

Comment: This is the default way of playing Url files as documented. I think you have not understood my question. All my MP3 files are in Embedded Resource Folder of PCL Project. I want to Add to Queue All these MP3 files so that they can be played one after another. As you have mentioned await  CrossMediaManager.Android.PlayFromAssembly(stringFilename, Assembly); only accepts one file. This command only accepts playing 1 file not the whole list of songs in Embedded resources.